# Darn you V=IR, you are wrong (does V really equal IR?)

Tags: ohms-law

Here is my simple reasoning. We apply a potential difference across a resistor. All the electrons begin responding. Since it takes time for electrons to respond, our current is not yet fully established. In fact, immediately after we apply the voltage, the current is zero! And yet we have a non-zero V and R. So am I wrong here, or does V sometimes not equal IR?

EDIT:
I'm having a bit of an issue here. People want to say that an inductance of zero will allow for instantaneous current initiation, but I wonder. Is it ever possible to accelerate an object with mass infinitely quickly with nothing but an electric field? Sounds impossible more than likely. I feel that an instantaneous acceleration can only be caused by an infinite amount of energy given.

Comment: If you're going to start modeling the movement of electrons, you have to do it throughout the circuit, including inside the power supply.  You can't take a "perfect" power supply and apply it to a "real world" circuit and expect to be able to disprove V=IR. Either use perfect components everywhere and try to disprove it, or practical components everywhere and try to disprove it, but mixing theory and practice will trip you up every time.

Comment: Could you define a perfect power supply? Do you mean that perhaps the power is applied too fast for a real power supply? I'm a bit confused on your logic, but thanks.

Comment: You tell me.  You say, *"We apply a potential difference"* but since you can't apply a potential difference instantaneously in the real world, then you need to model that part of the circuit as well before you can disprove V=IR. So describe what you mean by *"We apply a potential difference"* and how it actually works in your circuit where you are looking at electrons.

Comment: If you are still confused, consider the actual method of circuit creation.  Are you using a switch?  A semiconductor?  Are you just touching the wire to another piece of metal? Since you're looking at the movement of electrons, you have to consider that the interface between the two metals in a switch or wire to contact interface don't actually touch, they just get close enough to move electrons.  At first that interface is only a few atoms or molecules wide, but as you push them together it becomes larger. If it's a semiconductor there's ways to model that. Take it into account.

Comment: Aha! I see the heart of your problem. Suppose we have a Faraday cage blocking the field from the wire, which we instantaneously remove and apply the wire to the leads. Even if we move less-than instantly, the current will still take a finite amount of time to build up, so we only have to apply the wire before this point of build-up to defeat V=IR, in a non-steady state at least

Comment: Good one (as in good question)

Comment: The basics of Ohm's Law, is an aproximation similar to Newtonian Physics. Not 100% encompassing, but good enough for pretty much all intensive practial uses.

Comment: Right. A small flaw, in extreme circumstances, does no hurt in the overall usefulness of physical Laws/theories.

Comment: V=IR is completely applicable everywhere it completely applies. By trying to use an idealised formula and then argue non idealised circumstances you risk leading yourself astray. When you try to get down to moving electrons around you need also to start invoking quantum mechanical effects, look at drift velocity, decide whether electrons really exist as anything like the "lumps of stuff" form being posited for "getting things with mass moving" or are figments of a decades old super-simplified model, and more. Your heading might as well be eg "Darn you everything, nothing is ideal, why not?"

Comment: Actually, the mass of an electron is a physical quantity measured to be 9.11*10^-31 kg. That's completely alright if you want to argue against this at the quantum state but you'd have to argue against this seemingly defined mass, do you see what I mean? Personally, I'd leave that the mass is defined alone, you know? @R

Comment: @AndresSalas No one is arguing with you that it takes a finite amount of time for an electron to accelerate to a certain velocity (even if you ignore inductance). If you're interested in that time, you'll need to dive into relativistic physics and work out the calculations or head over to the physics forum. This is an electrical *engineering* forum where LOTS of shortcuts and generalizations are made. Newton wasn't wrong. His methods were simply approximations. Outside of a certain scope, using his methods would get you very wrong answers. Same thing here.

Comment: Ok great. Most people seem to think that instantaneous currents are possible ignoring this accelerational effect. Not to get into the details, but drift velocities are really slow, so idk if I would need relativity or not, the point being that it will take time and that until that time is finished V will not equal IR @horta thanks

Comment: @AndresSalas You're probably right about not needing relativistic physics, it's been awhile since I calculated drift velocities. I guess I'm trying to say, there's no reason to make a bunch of enemies here in the EE forums. If you want to learn, ask. If you want to teach, answer. Don't worry yourself in always being "right". There's plenty of stubborn people on these forums (and elsewhere). Age will do that I guess, but there's still a lot of fantastic free knowledge stored up in these older heads here. Use it wisely ;)

Comment: Yeah right? I worry I may have burned a number of bridges (you'll see my reputation sure has taken a hit lol), I'd say you're right. I'll try to keep myself plenty humile, a good comment @horta have a good day

Comment: Ohm's Law can be used for reactive , and nonlinear components, with transients, if we contrain it properly, e.g. use ESR*C for a family of products,   use ESR ratios for C dividers, Use Impedance ratios at a fixed f, Use linear saturation ESR values for  non-linear diodes and transistors, use L ratio's for unknown turns ratio, use V/f for back EMF, use DCR for motors etc. Use impedance(f) ratios for gain and attenuation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The only reason the current would be zero is if you have a non-zero inductance (which all circuits do). Once you factor in the inductance, you'll be able to calculate the rise time of the current after you apply a voltage. Only in the ideal world where there's no inductance or capacitance, will V=IR be true at all times over a resistor.

In our non-ideal world, you're right that V=IR only applies at steady state after the influence from capacitance and inductance fall away.

Comment: Phew. I was worried about that non-zero inductance comment until you said that all circuits have a non-zero inductance. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: +1 Yup. Even a straight wire has a bit of inductance. We're effectively measuring the inductance of a wire a few mm long to a part in a million or so.

Comment: Actually, in one sense your question is valid. When you apply a voltage across a resistor, it takes a finite amount of time for that information to propagate through the resistor, which will happen at approximately the speed of light. So you do get a delay of sorts, measured in picoseconds, probably. Of course, during the propagation time the current will be flowing in part of the resistor, so it's an "interesting question" whether current is flowing through the resistor.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, what I'm trying to think here is that not only does it take a while for the electrons to receive that information(electric field), it also takes another amount of time to accelerate to the drift velocity, but I think that resistance is constant so V=IR isn't quite correct for a period of time, including this time you describe.

Comment: Thank you @WhatRoughBeast, lots of doubters have come along in defense of Ohm's Law

Comment: Well, the doubters are more correct than you are, I think. First of all, Ohm's Law is only approximate, and it is more descriptive than prescriptive. It states that, for a useful class of materials, there is a uniform response of current to voltage changes. As a start, this is only true for a certain range of voltages and current (different for each material), and only for constant material temperature, and totally untrue for a whole bunch of materials such as semiconductors. You seem to have a picture of Ohm's Law as some ironclad ideal bit of natural legislation. It's not.

Comment: Thanks though. You can forgive my limited perspective as I'm only starting learning about all this.

Answer (score 8):

V=IR is only valid at steady state.

You are trying to apply it outside of that condition, so it doesn't always work. Transient Responses are not modeled at all in a 1st order system.

Comment: for all values of "steady state" less than the speed of light.

Comment: Transient response is so modeled for first order systems.

Comment: What @MattYoung said. A inductor circuit exhibits first order (transient) response.

Comment: The term "steady state" can also include periodic oscillatory behavior, if "R" is defined as being the complex impedance at the oscillating frequency.  A truly beautiful example of real-world phenomena following the rules of complex arithmetic.

Comment: @Horta said it right - "In our non-ideal world, you're right that V=IR only applies at steady state after the influence from capacitance and inductance fall away."

Answer (score 4):

You are assuming that voltage can be applied instantaneously (zero capacitance) but that current cannot rise instantaneously (non-zero inductance). You are also assuming a theoretically perfect resistor that always applies precisely the same resistance. These seem like an unreasonable set of assumptions.

> As far as the resistor goes, isn't it true that resistance can be calculated directly from resistivity at a given temperature?

Steady-state, theoretical resistance can. But the actual resistance displayed at a particular instant in time cannot. If you don't see why, imagine if we're sending electrons through one at a time.

Comment: I believe you may be on to something here. But, I have a few statements: firstly, an instantaneous voltage, as I explained to Adam Davis above, isn't a necessary assumption. It only needs to be applied fast enough, which is physically possible. Also, I am not 'assuming' that current cannot rise instantaneously, I feel that I am proving it. Instantaneous acceleration=infinite work. As far as the resistor goes, isn't it true that resistance can be calculated directly from resistivity at a given temperature? If that is true, I'm ok. I need more light though, thank you

Comment: @AndresSalas See update.

Comment: Which brings up the question: why then are resistors labeled as having a particular resistance, say 50 Ohms, even when voltages and current may vary as you say? So, in this idea you have, would the instantaneous resistance be huge or small? Huge right?

Comment: @AndresSalas Everyone understands what those resistance labels mean.

Comment: Uhoh. Seems like I missed that party. I'm confused, becasue initially you seem to state that a resistor has a non-constant value at specific times. Later on, you seem to argue the opposite point, which seems that a 50 Ohm resistor is a 50 Ohm resistor with a 50 Ohm resistance at all times. Apparently I don't understand what those little labels mean haha. I may ask you to define these labels if I'm missing out some point here

Comment: @AndresSalas Those little labels represent the design target for the steady-state ratio of voltage to current when the resistor is operating under its intended conditions. Due to things like non-zero inductance (and manufacturing tolerance, environmental conditions, and so on), they will not always be the instantaneous ratio of voltage to current.

Comment: When the initial voltage is applied, what then is the initial (or slightly post-initial) real resistance? Smaller, or larger than the steady state resistance

Comment: @AndresSalas It's really a matter of definition. You can say it's larger, but that would essentially be modelling inductance as a varying resistance.

Comment: See edit. I wonder, is even a zero-inductance capable of meaning that we can infinitely quickly accelerate point charges using only an electric field?

Comment: @AndresSalas Zero inductance is impossible, as is zero capacitance. Zero resistance, on the other hand, ...

Comment: Uhoh. Even a superconductor? Assuming we have all these things, zero inductance, capacitance, impedance, reactance (redundant) etc., would we still not have this issue with a time-delayed response to an applied potential difference? Hope I am still thinking well and coherently, thanks for the replies...

Comment: Oh! You said impossible, not possible, whoops. Ignore response. Ah, so even if we have a superconductor, we would still have a magnetic field to build and capacitance to worry over. Does this effect my proposition though

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers mention that there are AC effects and things like inductance and capacitance.  But there is a bit more than that.

The thing is, you can't apply the voltage instantly anyway across all parts of the circuit, because you are limited by the speed of light.  Assuming a perfect circuit, the moment the voltage is applied you have an electromagnetic wave propagating down the wire at near the speed of light.  The actual movement of the electrons is [much slower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity) and doesn't come into play here, the energy (and voltage) is propogated in the EM wave.  So V=IR isn't being violated at all, because your current is propagating near light speed with the voltage.

Comment: A poor answer. The electrons respond near-instantaneously with the EM wave (although wait a minute here, are you thinking of a straight wire? Cuz a short, bent wire is not driven by the electric field from the battery, but from the electric field propogated from the battery through the individual atoms which create dipoles. The electric field is bent through the creation of dipoles, which is dependent on electron movement, which is slow.)
They may respond at the speed of light, but they do not accelerate to the Ohm's Law current speed instantaneously, that is impossible.

Comment: Hope I do not come negatively across here (see what I mean, negatively...electronegatively...haha) I appreciate the example

Answer (score 0):

@AndresSalas
Its all in the definition.
An ohm is equivalent to a volt per ampere.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor

All this applies to DC (direct current) circuits, using AC or changing voltage/current will have additional effects like impedance and capacitance.

If you are doing this quickly (your instantaneous voltage) then you no longer have pure DC characteristics and have to factor in impedance and capacitance to the equation for how it will behave.
Electrical Impedance seems more appropriate to what you are trying to do.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance

See if that doesn't help answer your thoughts.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying, this is basically (but not quite, since the voltage isn't applied in reverse) the first step in an ac sinusoidal voltage application.